# node_modules/@newrelic/native-metrics: Command failed. node_modules/couchbase: Command failed. Exit code: 127

Tags: typescript, nestjs, node-modules, couchbase, newrelic

In macbook m1 pro 2021, ventura 13.5 I have a project that I developed in typescript. It uses yarn, it's supposed to work fine when I do

```
yarn build

yarn install

yarn start
```

my versions:

```
`yarn -v 
1.22.19`

` npm -v
9.8.1
`

`node -v
v20.5.0
```

These are the versions and I need to use couchbase version 3.2.1

I think that the problem is with macbook m1 chip, but not sure

when I do `yarn build` it gives this output:

```
> yarn run v1.22.19
> $ rimraf dist
> $ nest build
> DeprecationWarning: blabla
> ✨  Done in 3.73s.
```

and then I run the command `yarn install` but it gives this output and then it blocks me to run `yarn start` command:

```
> yarn install v1.22.19
> [1/4]   Resolving packages...
> [2/4]   Fetching packages...
> [3/4]   Linking dependencies...
> some warnings about nestjs, eslint, tsloader etc.
> [4/4]   Building fresh packages...
> [6/7] ⠂ @nestjs/core
> [-/7] ⠂ waiting...
> 3/7] ⠂ couchbase
> [-/7] ⠂ waiting...
> warning Error running install script for optional dependency: "/Users/user1/project1/node_modules/@newrelic/native-metrics: Command failed.
> Exit code: 1
> Command: node ./lib/pre-build.js install native_metrics
> Arguments: 
> Directory: /Users/user1/project1/node_modules/@newrelic/native-metrics
> Output:
> ============================================================================
> Attempting install in native-metrics module. Please note that this is an
> OPTIONAL dependency, and any resultant errors in this process will not
> affect the general performance of the New Relic agent, but event loop and
> garbage collection metrics will not be collected.
> ============================================================================
> [6/7] ⡀ @nestjs/core
> [-/7] ⡀ waiting...
> [3/7] ⡀ couchbase
> [-/7] ⡀ waiting...
> error /Users/user1/project1/node_modules/couchbase: Command failed.
> Exit code: 127
> Command: prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
> Arguments: 
> Directory: /Users/user1/project1/node_modules/couchbase
```

I tried this one: https://github.com/tj/n and I tried many other solutions but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: We might not have couchbase native binaries ready for node 20, could you try with node 18 and see if you have the same error ?

Comment: FIXED!!! 
yeah it was the main problem i think so, best approach to solve it:

install nvm in your machine, it is really useful to switch node versions, then use node 18, it worked with node 18 perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use node 18,

in order to not to uninstall node 20, just install nvm in your local, [how to](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-version-manager-nvm-install-guide/)

then use node 18 like follows

`nvm use 18`

then do same commands for the rest, such as yarn install, build etc...